# Is it safe to water my plants with diluted Trisodium Phosphate (TSP)?

Tags: botany

I occasionally use TSP (Sodium Triphosphate) to degrease and clean mechanical parts for restoration work. It's very effective, but I'm a bit concerned about dumping the resulting waste solution down the drain. TSP is known to aggressively promote ecologically destructive algae growth in lakes and ponds. Rather than negatively contribute to the environment, I figure the waste could be used for a more positive purpose.

Is it safe to water my house and outdoor plants with it? I've encountered conflicting information with some claiming TSP is deadly to plants, while others claim phosphates are excellent fertilizers. I suspect the phosphates are fine, but TSP's sodium content might be akin to using salt on plant. I also suspect TSP maybe too basic and needs to be neutralized with a mild acid such as citric or acetic acid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TSP as fertilizer, especially recently as fertilizer prices have increased. The concern is the alkalinity, however my soil is near pH 5 so no problem. It is unlikely your house plant soil is very acidic so that is a bad idea in a limited quantity of soil. Outside use will depend on soil pH, although small amounts would not be a problem.